# How to lock two resource at once?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, posix, mutex

I'm trying to solve a problem similar to the dining philosophers one. How can I lock two resources at one moment? Locking one resource and then waiting for the other is not the best option.

I can use only condition variables and mutexes, but the only solution is the "not-the-best one".

I'm writing in C.

Comment: This is a good read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/sync-12/index.html

Comment: Use the `std::lock` template, which locks an arbitrary number of mutexes in a deadlock-free way.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm writing in C.

Comment: @pmichna: then implement what std::lock does, in C.

Answer (score -3):

`std::lock` can take two arguments, two unique_locks. Call them both with `std::defer_lock' argument:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_one(mutex_one, std::defer_lock);
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_two(mutex_two, std::defer_lock);
std::lock(lock_one, lock_two);`
```

Comment: I'm writing in C, not C++.

Comment: We'll believe you if you keep saying it enough :)

Comment: Downvoted? You only added "I'm writing in C" after two of us answered in C++.

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian, the question has only been tagged C from the beginning. A C++ reply is simply inappropriate, I think, and not very helpfull.

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian Apart from the `C` tag being there all the time, I wrote about writing in C after the similar answer appeared in the comments and that was before your answer.

Comment: Our answers crossed, if you look at the timing. No biggie, anyway.

Comment: -1 for providing a C++ answer to a C question; it wasted my time.